# Argument type 'String.Type' does not conform to expected type 'StringProtocol' in Swift

Tags: swift, swift4, swift-protocols

I'm using a Table View with Search bar that takes multiple search inputs and filters the table, but I'm getting the following message:

"Argument type 'String.Type' does not conform to expected type 'StringProtocol'"

```swift
var arrayFilter = [[]]
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    self.arrayFilter = array.filter{
        if let pos = ($0[0] as! String).lowercased().range(of:String)(searchText.lowercaseString) {
            return (pos.startIndex == ($0[0] as! String).startIndex)
        }
        return false
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

The line that throws the error is:

```swift
if let pos = ($0[0] as! String).lowercased().range(of:String)(searchText.lowercaseString) {
return (pos.startIndex == ($0[0] as! String).startIndex)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you just have a typo in there.  Actually this shouldn't compile at all as it's not valid Swift code.

The issue is here:

```
.range(of:String)(searchText.lowercaseString)
```

You need to change to:

```
.range(of: searchText.lowercaseString)
```